# Android, Changing activity background color while keeping the buttons original color (without applying the background color to the button)

Tags: android

I have an activity with green background.
The activity theme was "@android:style/Theme.Light" and I change it to be "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light".
Now all the buttons get the green color as well (also edit texts) while with the old theme they had the standard gray color.

I want to change the theme because the old one doesn't have action bar while Holo theme does.

I prefer not the create button style (9-patch) using http://android-holo-colors.com/ but just change the theme item setting if possible:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
```

This is my activity in the manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".editrecord.TimeInActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/green" 
    android:fillViewport="true"   
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/save_list_main_menu_button_height"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:textSize="@dimen/save_list_main_menu_text_size"
                android:text="@string/main_menu" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/display_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:textSize="@dimen/save_list_main_menu_text_size"
                android:text="@string/display_menu" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saved_records_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:textSize="@dimen/save_list_main_menu_text_size"
                android:text="@string/saved_records_list" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save_recordButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:textSize="@dimen/save_list_main_menu_text_size"
                android:text="@string/save_record" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `AppCompat`, not `Holo`. Just set the background color in the XML, not the styles.

Comment: Jared, thanks for your respond. The reason that I want to change the theme, is that I want to have the action bar in the top of the screen, as you can see in this article: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html I should use Holo theme for it. In the article it mention using AppCompat only for version befoe API 11. but mostly care about version above API11.

Comment: No. This is an outdated article. Please see: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/tree/master/app/src/main